# Flutter App won't build appbundle/APK or run on Android after android studio 3.5

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Basically my app run and build on iOS but doesn't on Android anymore after I updated Android studio to 3.5 version and i really need to be able to post a release on the playstore.

I've tried lots of things but nothing works i'm looking forward for someone to give me the solution to my problem ! I'm desperate !

Here is my **flutter doctor -v** log :

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.9.1+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15 19A602, locale en-FR)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.5 at /Users/axel/flutter
    • Framework revision 1aedbb1835 (6 days ago), 2019-10-17 08:37:27 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/axel/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.1, Build version 11A1027
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 40.2.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.39.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.5.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to modify the build.gradle in android>app>build.gradle with this :

```
buildTypes {
       release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       //minifyEnabled true
       //useProguard true
      //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
```

then you can:

```
flutter clean
flutter build appbundle --release
```

Comment: do you mean i should comment minify, useprogard and proguardfile ?

Comment: yes you have to comment on these lines and then execute the 
flutter clean and flutter build appbundle --release

Answer (score 0):

My **pubspec.yaml**

```
name: [secret]
description: [secret]

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 0.1.43

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  shared_preferences: ^0.5.2
  cached_network_image: ^1.1.1
  flutter_svg: ^0.13.1
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  flutter_bloc: ^0.11.1
  equatable: ^0.1.6
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.2.1
  local_auth: ^0.6.0+1
  http_auth: ^0.2.5
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  firebase_messaging: ^5.1.6
  validate: ^1.7.0
  kiwi: ^0.1.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.1
  flutter_crashlytics: ^1.0.0
  flutter_sticky_header: ^0.4.0
  dio: ^2.1.0
  auto_size_text: ^1.1.1
  flutter_masked_text: ^0.8.0
  permission_handler: '^3.2.0'
  path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
  flutter_email_sender: ^2.0.0
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
  contacts_service: ^0.2.8
  geolocator: ^5.1.1+1
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.20+1
  url_launcher: ^5.0.2
  qr_mobile_vision: ^0.2.2
  qr_flutter: ^2.0.0+51
  csv: ^4.0.3
  share_extend: ^1.0.8
  country_pickers: ^1.1.0
  diacritic: ^0.1.1
  recase: ^2.0.1
  keyboard_visibility: ^0.5.6

  flutter_worldpay:
    path: ../flutter_worldpay/

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  uses-material-design: true

  fonts:
    - family: Lato
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Lato.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Lato-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
    - family: Nunito
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Nunito.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Nunito-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/Nunito-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

And finally the results of my **flutter build appbundle --verbose** :

```
[   +1 ms] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_crashlytics-1.0.0/android/src/main/java/com/kiwi/fluttercrashlytics/Utils.java:11: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[   +2 ms]         final List<Map<String, Object>> traces = (List<Map<String, Object>>) exception.get("trace");
[        ]                                                                                           ^
[ +157 ms]   required: List<Map<String,Object>>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_crashlytics-1.0.0/android/src/main/java/com/kiwi/fluttercrashlytics/FlutterCrashlyticsPlugin.java:52: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[        ]                         final List<Object> info = (List<Object>) call.arguments;
[        ]                                                                      ^
[        ]   required: List<Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_crashlytics-1.0.0/android/src/main/java/com/kiwi/fluttercrashlytics/FlutterCrashlyticsPlugin.java:87: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[        ]                 final Map<String, Object> exception = (Map<String, Object>) call.arguments;
[  +15 ms]                                                                                 ^
[        ]   required: Map<String,Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] 3 warnings
[+4221 ms] > Task :flutter_email_sender:compileReleaseKotlin

                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
[        ] /Users/axel/Documents/CSC/flutter_worldpay/android/src/main/java/com/corsicoin/flutter_worldpay/FlutterWorldpayPlugin.java:55: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
[        ]             final HashMap<String, String> args = (HashMap) call.arguments;
[  +33 ms]                                                  ^
[        ]   required: HashMap<String,String>
[        ]   found:    HashMap
[        ] 1 warning
[ +597 ms] > Task :google_maps_flutter:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:244: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[        ]           markersController.addMarkers((List<Object>) markersToAdd);
[        ]                                                       ^
[        ]   required: List<Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:246: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[        ]           markersController.changeMarkers((List<Object>) markersToChange);
[        ]                                                          ^
[  +11 ms]   required: List<Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:248: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[        ]           markersController.removeMarkers((List<Object>) markerIdsToRemove);
[        ]                                                          ^
[        ]   required: List<Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:255: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[        ]           polygonsController.addPolygons((List<Object>) polygonsToAdd);
[        ]                                                         ^
[        ]   required: List<Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:257: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[        ]           polygonsController.changePolygons((List<Object>) polygonsToChange);
[        ]                                                            ^
[        ]   required: List<Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:259: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[        ]           polygonsController.removePolygons((List<Object>) polygonIdsToRemove);
[  +10 ms]                                                            ^
[        ]   required: List<Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:266: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[        ]           polylinesController.addPolylines((List<Object>) polylinesToAdd);
[        ]                                                           ^
[        ]   required: List<Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:268: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[        ]           polylinesController.changePolylines((List<Object>) polylinesToChange);
[ +319 ms]                                                              ^
[        ]   required: List<Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:270: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[        ]           polylinesController.removePolylines((List<Object>) polylineIdsToRemove);
[        ]                                                              ^
[        ]   required: List<Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:277: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[  +72 ms]           circlesController.addCircles((List<Object>) circlesToAdd);
[        ]                                                       ^
[        ]   required: List<Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:279: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[        ]           circlesController.changeCircles((List<Object>) circlesToChange);
[        ]                                                          ^
[        ]   required: List<Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:281: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[ +285 ms]           circlesController.removeCircles((List<Object>) circleIdsToRemove);
[        ]                                                          ^
[        ]   required: List<Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:573: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[        ]     this.initialMarkers = (List<Object>) initialMarkers;
[        ]                                          ^
[        ]   required: List<Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:585: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[ +142 ms]     this.initialPolygons = (List<Object>) initialPolygons;
[        ]                                           ^
[        ]   required: List<Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:597: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[        ]     this.initialPolylines = (List<Object>) initialPolylines;
[        ]                                            ^
[        ]   required: List<Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:609: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[ +457 ms]     this.initialCircles = (List<Object>) initialCircles;
[        ]                                          ^
[        ]   required: List<Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/Convert.java:352: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
[        ]       interpretInfoWindowOptions(sink, (Map<String, Object>) infoWindow);
[        ]                                                              ^
[        ]   required: Map<String,Object>
[        ]   found:    Object
[        ] 17 warnings
[        ] 
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .

[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/android/src/main/java/com/github/rmtmckenzie/qrmobilevision/QrCameraC1.java:6: warning: [deprecation] Camera in android.hardware has been
deprecated
[        ] import android.hardware.Camera;
[        ]                        ^
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/android/src/main/java/com/github/rmtmckenzie/qrmobilevision/QrCameraC1.java:7: warning: [deprecation] Camera in android.hardware has been
deprecated
[        ] import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
[        ]                        ^
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/android/src/main/java/com/github/rmtmckenzie/qrmobilevision/QrCameraC1.java:7: warning: [deprecation] Camera in android.hardware has been
deprecated
[ +108 ms] import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
[        ]                        ^
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/android/src/main/java/com/github/rmtmckenzie/qrmobilevision/QrCameraC1.java:7: warning: [deprecation] Camera.Size in Camera has been
deprecated
[        ] import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
[        ]                               ^
[        ] 4 warnings
[        ] > Task :qr_mobile_vision:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
[        ] > Task :share_extend:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :share_extend:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
[        ] > Task :shared_preferences:generateReleaseBuildConfig
[  +48 ms] > Task :shared_preferences:prepareLintJar
[        ] > Task :shared_preferences:generateReleaseSources
[        ] > Task :shared_preferences:javaPreCompileRelease
[ +138 ms] > Task :shared_preferences:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
[        ] > Task :shared_preferences:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :shared_preferences:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease

                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .

[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.1.2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/urllauncher/WebViewActivity.java:42: warning: [deprecation] shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView,String) in
WebViewClient has been deprecated
[   +1 ms]         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
[        ]                        ^
[        ] /Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.1.2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/urllauncher/WebViewActivity.java:47: warning: [deprecation] shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView,String) in
WebViewClient has been deprecated
[   +1 ms]           return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
[        ]                       ^
[        ] 2 warnings
[+1308 ms] > Task :app:compileReleaseKotlin
[        ] > Task :app:prepareLintJar
[        ] > Task :app:generateReleaseSources
[  +88 ms] > Task :app:javaPreCompileRelease
[+4599 ms] > Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
[        ] > Task :app:validateSigningRelease FAILED
[        ]          *********************************************************
[        ] WARNING: This version of firebase_core will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
[        ]          See [somelink] for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
[        ]          This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
[        ]          *********************************************************
[        ] 335 actionable tasks: 334 executed, 1 up-to-date
[ +460 ms] Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... (completed in 322.4s, longer than expected)
[   +7 ms] "flutter appbundle" took 338,203ms.
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:751:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      buildGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:494:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      buildAppBundle (package:flutter_tools/src/android/app_bundle.dart:43:10)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      BuildAppBundleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_appbundle.dart:47:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:490:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:407:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:154:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#10     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#11     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#12     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:397:20)
#14     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:402:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:154:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#18     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#19     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#20     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#21     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#22     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:356:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#23     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:25)
#24     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
#25     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:14)
#26     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:242:18)
#27     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:63:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#30     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#31     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1500:12)
#32     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:61:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#33     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:154:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#34     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#35     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#36     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#37     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#38     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#39     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:59:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#40     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:50:10)
#41     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:65:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#42     main (file:///Users/axel/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#43     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:303:32)
#44     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to complete these steps:

---

**1.** add this line: `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` to your **android > app > build.gradle** -- `andorid` > `buildTypes` > `release`

```
    android {
    
      ...
    
      buildTypes{
        release{
          ...
          signingConfig signingConfigs.release
          ...
        }
      }
    
      ...
    
    }
```

---

**2.** close and open android studio again. PS: also if you done the first step before days or months

---

Hope it helps!